# Как разделить строку на отдельные столбцы?

Tags: sql, oracle

Допустим содержимое поля имеет запись: Иванов Иван Иванович

Какими средствами можно разбить это поле на три поля (отдельно фамилия, имя, отчество)?

Comment: *Какими средствами* Встроенными функциями работы со строками. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions002.htm#SQLRF20032

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать комбинации `INSTR` и `SUBSTR`

```
with Students as (
    select level id, 'fname'||level||' mname'||level||' lname'||level fullName from dual  
    connect by level <= 3
)
select s.*,
       substr(s.fullName, 1, instr(s.fullName, ' ', 1, 1) - 1 ) as fName,
       substr(s.fullName, instr(s.fullName, ' ', 1, 1),  instr(s.fullName, ' ', 1, 2) - instr(s.fullName, ' ', 1, 1) ) as mName,
       substr(s.fullName, instr(s.fullName, ' ', 1, 2) ) as lName
  from Students s
```